# How do i resolve "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ownerDocument')"

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom

I am trying to add a div inside the main div on page loading, it works when i write the code like this:

```
function DivAdder() {
  $('#mainDiv').append('<div class="newspaper-wrapper"></div>');
}
DivAdder();
window.onload = DivAdder;
```

But i want to make this function have a parameter so i can just pass its name instead of writing the whole string in .append function. I wrote something like this but i am having the error from the title:

```
function DivAdder(variable) {
  $('#mainDiv').append($(variable));
}
DivAdder('<div class="newspaper_wrapper"></div>');
window.onload = DivAdder;
```

And i tried this as well:

```
$('#mainDiv').append(variable);
```

But nothing happens. I read some documentation but was not successful.
Appreciate the help <3 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `window.onload` passes an Event object as first argument. If you `console.log(variable)`, it will tell you it's an Event.

You need to keep this first argument as an optional event, and pass your HTML as second argument :

```js
function DivAdder($event, html) {
  console.log("Event = ", $event)
    console.log("Adding div : " , html)
  $('#mainDiv').append(html);
}
DivAdder(null, '<div class="newspaper_wrapper">TEST</div>');
window.onload = DivAdder; // This will call DivAdder( LoadEvent )
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mainDiv"></div>
```

I'm not sure why you're assigning `window.onload = DivAdder` in the first place, since this won't add any HTML and won't do anything at all. You can get rid of it completely, it's only causing trouble.

```js
function DivAdder(html) {
    console.log("Adding div : " , html)
  $('#mainDiv').append(html);
}
DivAdder('<div class="newspaper_wrapper">TEST</div>');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mainDiv"></div>
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for helping, i tried the code u send and it still doesn't work. I cannot see any divs getting displayed on the page.

Comment: Well.. you copied it wrong then :) Because run my snippet, it works

Comment: Well, i checked multiple times. Idk why but it doesnt work. It prints on console but doesnt add anything on the page.

Comment: checked the code on JSFIddle, and it works, it doenst work on my browser tho. Idk what could be the problem